# onReceive method not getting called

Tags: android, intentservice, android-intentservice

I've tried to send a Broadcast from a service to an Activity with `IntentService`, for that I've used the following code:

```
public class NotifyService extends IntentService {

    public NotifyService() {
        super("NotifyService");
    }

    // will be called asynchronously by Android
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.d("onHandleIntent", "start service");
        publishResults();
    }

    private void publishResults() {

        result = Activity.RESULT_OK;
        Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
}
```

then I define my Receiver in an Activity class like:

```
public BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("TAG", "receiver");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


        if (bundle != null) {
            int resultCode = bundle.getInt(NotifyService.RESULT);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "after service work.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();                    
            }
        }

         stopService(new Intent(Home.this,NotifyService.class));
    }
};
```

I've used `registerReceiver` in `onResume` and `unregisterReceiver` in `onPause` method

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(NotifyService.NOTIFICATION));
```

But the `onReceive` method not getting called,

I've used section 7 of [This Site](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

what have I missed?

**Edit**

did I have any alternative solution? I've try to notify activity from service to update data.

Comment: Are you sure that your service was started? `Log.d("onHandleIntent", "start service");` this log was printed?

Comment: yes @ArtemZinnatullin

Comment: May be you sending BroadCast intent when your receiver is not registered? Because your code seems normally :)

Comment: @ArtemZinnatullin I register Receiver in `onResume` method, and i send broadcast when activity is running, so I think there is no reason that receiver not registered. Thanks for reply

Comment: You shouldn't have to explicitly use `stopService` on an `IntentService`, that's already handled for you. Although I doubt that's the source of your problem...

Comment: @MattiasBuelens what is your mean about `I doubt that's the source of your problem`?

Comment: @user2910110 I don't think your problem is caused by you calling `stopService`, as that would imply that `onReceive` *was* called. It has to be something else, and I don't know what. So treat my comment more like a side note.

Comment: oh, thanks for mention @MattiasBuelens , don't have any idea for my problem?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens did I have any alternative solution? I've try to notify activity from service to update data. can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure why your original code is not working. However, if you want application-local broadcasts, you might want to use a [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) instead of regular cross-application broadcasts.

Use this in your service:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and these in your activity:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver,
        new IntentFilter(NotifyService.NOTIFICATION));

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

Let me know if this changes anything. Again, I don't see why your original code doesn't work, so this is more of a guess.

Comment: thanks man, I have problem in my code, I start another activity so `onPause()` of this activity have been called and then `unregisterReceiver` called, so `onReceive` not getting called, I fixed my problem but your code worked too, thanks for reply.

Comment: @user2910110 That explains a lot. Of course, if you unregister in `onPause`, you won't receive the broadcast when your activity is no longer on the foreground!